# remove rows with empty values - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am trying to do some simple program where I want to remove a row which has Empty/NUll values(without using DataFrame).
I tried to do it with filter but it's not working. Can you please tell where I am making the mistake ?

**Data:**

```
Bypass Road (film),2019,137,Drama|Thriller,7.1,51
Satellite Shankar,2019,135,Action|Drama,4.6,34
Jhalki,2019,0,Drama,,
Marjaavaan,2019,0,Action|Romance,,
Motichoor Chaknachoor,2019,150,Comedy|Romance,,
Keep Safe Distance (film),2019,0,Action|Thriller,,
```

I am trying to remove rows with empty value like `Keep Safe Distance (film),2019,0,Action|Thriller,,`

**Code:**

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("MovieAnalyzer")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val dataRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("src/test/resources/movies.csv")

    // remove the header
    val header = dataRDD.first()
    val movie_list = dataRDD.filter(line => line != header).filter(r => !r.contains("")).map(r => r.replace("\\N","0"))
    movie_list.collect().foreach(println)
```

The above code is not printing any data from the csv file. Please let me know what is the problem with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with 
`.filter(r => !r.contains(""))`

you should split these values and then perform check :

`dataRDD.filter(s=> !s.split(",",-1).contains("")).foreach(println(_))`

so output will be:

`Bypass Road (film),2019,137,Drama|Thriller,7.1,51
Satellite Shankar,2019,135,Action|Drama,4.6,34`

If `RDD` is not required I would use `DataFrame` and then `DataFrameNaFunctions` like below:

```
val df = ss.read.csv("data/movies.csv")
df.na.drop().show();
```

output:

```
+------------------+----+---+--------------+---+---+
|               _c0| _c1|_c2|           _c3|_c4|_c5|
+------------------+----+---+--------------+---+---+
|Bypass Road (film)|2019|137|Drama|Thriller|7.1| 51|
| Satellite Shankar|2019|135|  Action|Drama|4.6| 34|
+------------------+----+---+--------------+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks man it worked. can you please explain me why code didnt how. what's wrong with my code ?